# Make <table> id and <tr> id constant while rendering Python df.to_html() table from flask using Jinja2 template {{table|safe}}

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

```
**Flask code:**

def prgrm():
    sqldf = sql_df('engine_table', db.engine)  # df of main data
    date = sqldf.iloc[-1]['Date']  # date of one day less
    date_2 = sqldf.iloc[-2]['Date']
    date1 = pd.to_datetime(date).strftime('%d-%b-%y')
    date2 = (pd.to_datetime(date) + pd.DateOffset(1)).strftime('%d-%b-%y')
    date3 = pd.to_datetime(date_2).strftime('%d-%b-%y')

    df_1 = sqldf.loc[~sqldf.Date.isin([date])]  # df not in last date
    df_1_emo = EMO(df_1, (33, 38))  # EMO upto 29-Apr-2019

    df_2 = sqldf[sqldf.Date == date]  # df of 30-Apr-2019
    df_2 = df_2[['Engine', 'DRHRS', 'DSENTOUT', 'EFF']]
    df_2 = df_2.sort_values(by=['DRHRS', 'DSENTOUT', 'EFF'], ascending=False, ignore_index=True)
    # df_2.index = range(1, 33)
    # df_2.index = range(1, df_2.index[-1]+2)
    df_2 = df_2.round(2)
    # df_2.rename_axis("Rank", axis='columns', inplace=True)
    df_2["Rank"] = range(1, 33)
    df_2 = df_2[["Rank", "Engine", "DRHRS", "DSENTOUT", "EFF"]]
    a = df_1_emo[["Rank", "Engine"]]
    b = df_2[["Rank", "Engine"]]
    df_2['EMO_Rank'] = list(b.merge(a, how="left", on="Engine")["Rank_y"])


    df_3_emo = EMO(sqldf, (33, 38))  # EMO upto 30-Apr-2019

    table_1 = Style_Table(df_1_emo, 'EMO for {}'.format(date1))
    table_2 = Style_Table_2(df_2, 'Statistics for {}'.format(date1))
    table_3 = Style_Section(df_3_emo, 'EMO made upto {}'.format(date2))

    return table_1,table_2,table_3

def Style_Table_2(df_f,capt):
    df_html = df_f.style.set_caption(capt).format({"EFF": "{:,.2f}%"})\
        .set_precision(2)\
        .bar(subset=["EFF"], color='#6BB3C7')\
        .set_table_styles([{'selector': 'caption', 'props': [('display', 'table-caption'), ('text-align', 'center'),('font-size', '20px'), ('caption-side', 'top'),("color", "#3700ff")]},\
        {'selector': ['table', 'th', 'td', 'tr'],'props': [('border', '1px solid black')]}])\
        .set_table_attributes('class="table table-sm"')\
        .apply(lambda x: ["background:#ff6a00" if (v > 38 or v < 33) else "" for v in x],subset=["EFF"])\
        .apply(lambda x: ["color:#f2ff00" if (v > 38 or v < 33) else "" for v in x], subset=["EFF"])\
        .hide_index()\
        .apply(highlight_greater, axis=None)\
        .render()

    return df_html
    @app.route('/emo_next_day')
    def emo_next_day():
        a, b, c = prgrm()
        weekly_eff_table = weekly_eff((33, 38), 7)
        date_val = weekly_eff_table.Date.dt.strftime("%d-%b-%y").to_list()
        eff_val = weekly_eff_table.Wavg_Eff.to_list()
        return render_template('db_html_table_next_day.html', table3=c, \
                               weekly_eff_table=weekly_eff_table.to_html(), date_val=date_val, eff_val=eff_val)

    
**Html code:**

    {% extends "dbbase.html" %}
    
    {% block content %}
    
    <div class="container">
        {{ table3|safe }}
    </div>
    
    {% endblock %}
```

Is there any way to make table id and tr ids constant while rendering table from flask Python in HTML using Jinja2 template? Every time I refresh the page then table id keeps on changing, hence unable to use DOM manipulation in HTML. Thanks in advance. Flask code and HTML code are attached.

Comment: Please provide your html and Flask code

Comment: Please add your code in your main question in code format.